# Git LFS: Where are the files stored before they are pushed?

Tags: git, github, git-lfs, git-lfs-migrate

I added git LFS to a repository and wanted to convert a few already committed files to LFS objects. I ran the following command:
`git lfs migrate import --include="*.shelf"`

Now in my local repository, all `*.shelf` files have been replaced with text pointers.

I then ran a `git push`, but unfortunately, the sizes of my files were too big even for LFS, and the command caused an error. Now all I have is text pointers and do not know how to get my original files back.

Surely they must be saved somewhere locally before they were pushed?

How do I get my original files back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I get my original files back?

Check first if [`git lfs-checkout`](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-checkout.1.ronn) would work.

> Try to ensure that the working copy contains file content for Git LFS objects for the current ref, if the object data is available.
> Does not download any content, see [git-lfs-fetch](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-fetch.1.ronn) for that.

As documented in "[What does git lfs migrate do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51782043/6309)":

> the original git-objects of the binary files are still in the .git folder

> The content of the file is stored in the `.git/lfs/objects` folder