# Git LFS: File successfully uploaded to LFS server but I still get the 'file too large' error

Tags: git, github, git-lfs, gitattributes

I have a large file so I'm using git LFS to manage pushing it to the repo.
I successfully installed git lfs following [this](https://git-lfs.github.com).

Then I added git FLS to my repo:

> git lfs install

Then I made git lfs track the file:

```
git lfs track "path/to/large/file"
```

This creates the **.gitattributes** file:

> path/to/large/file filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

Then I tried to push it:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Add large file lfs"
git push
```

I see the file being uploaded successfully to LFS server.
But, I'm surprised at the end that the process crashes and I see the same **File too large** error:

```
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (1/1), 110 MB | 0 B/s, done.                                                  
Counting objects: 15, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Writing objects: 100% (15/15), 743.49 KiB | 13.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 15 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (8/8), completed with 5 local objects.
remote: error: Trace: c5326be9306bc498b3d01095deb0bbc4dad4439ad12cb1584197cc59d55a7874
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File path/to/large/file is 105.26 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://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@github.com/AGSTRANGER/lodeep.git
 ! [remote rejected] update/280223 -> update/280223 (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://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@github.com/AGSTRANGER/lodeep.git'
```

Not really sure what's wrong and what I should do.
I thought I did what I had to do.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61602985/736079

Comment: I would assume the large file is still in the history of your git repo. You've only moved the file to LFS in the new commit. You'll need to run `git lfs migrate` to rewrite history and move all previous versions of the file to LFS or do an interactive rebase to remove the older versions of the file from history. Tools like `bfg-repo-cleaner` and `git-filter-repo` can also be of use.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51782043/what-does-git-lfs-migrate-do